# BouncyCastle generating random number with SP800SecureRandom

Tags: android, random, bouncycastle

I want to create number numbers with BouncyCastle SP800SecureRandom. But i cant find any document and example about that. Can you give a source or an example that can help with the subject?

Answer (score 1):

To get an instance from `SP800SecureRandom` you need to get it through the `SP800SecureRandomBuilder` class.

The following steps are based on the type of the random-number-generator you are targeting. If a DRNG (Deterministic Random Number Generator) is required then you need to initialize the builder with an instance of a secure random, which is PRNG (Pseudo Random Number Generator) by itself. Likely, the same `BouncyCastle` package provide an implementation for thin in the class `FixedSecureRandom`. Noting that, additionally, you would need to set the "predictionResistant" to `false` to avoid reseeding with every call. On the other hand, i.e. not need to be DRNG, you could use the default constructor, which requires no inputs at all and depends on the platform default SecureRandom implementation.
After getting an instance of the `SP800SecureRandomBuilder` class, then you just need to build it to get an instance of `SP800SecureRandom`. Here you had three building options, as per the algorithm type you need your random number generation instance to follow. The three options are

1. `buildHMAC`
2. `buildHash`
3. `buildCTR`

. Each of the builder methods requires its own set of parameters, as per the algorithm requirements.
Following is an example of initializing two different instances with two different algorithms:

1- Hash-based SP800SecureRandom:

```
hashDRNG = SP800SecureRandomBuilder(FixedSecureRandom(seed), false)
.buildHash(SHA256Digest(), seed, false);
```

2- HMac-based SP800SecureRandom:

```
 hmacDRNG = SP800SecureRandomBuilder(FixedSecureRandom(seed), false)
.buildHMAC(HMac(SHA256Digest()), seed, false);
```